# В чем ошибка в программе - язык С++?

Tags: c++, блок-схема

Я только начала изучать язык С++ и поэтому пока плохо разбираюсь. Мне нужно создать программу по блок-схеме. Я вообщем-то написала ее, но почему-то при подстановке значений переменных выходит тот же результат, что и при обычном выполнении. Что не так в этой программе. Помогите пожалуйста!!!!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
'''
#include <iostream>
#include <string> //  поддержка строк
using namespace std; // использую данное пространство имен

int main() // главная форма программы
{
    int X; { // ввод переменной
     cout <<"X\n"; // вывод переменной на экран
    }
    int Y; { // ввод переменной
     cout <<"Y\n"; // вывод переменной на экран
    }
    int S; // ввод переменной

    int A,B,C,D,E; // ввод переменных

    if (Y>=2) { // если Y больше или равно 2
      S==0; // то площадь равна 0
    }
    else {
      (X>=2); // иначе Х больше или равно 2
    }
    if (X>=2) { // если Х больше или равно 2
      S==0; // то площадь равна 0
    }
    else {
      Y>=0; // иначе Y больше или равно 0
    }
    if (Y>=0) { // если Y больше или равно 0
      X^2+Y^2<=1; // то X^2+Y^2 меньше или равно 1
    }
    else {
      X>=0; // то X больше или равно 0
    }
    if (X^2+Y^2<=1) { // если X^2+Y^2 меньше или равно 1
       (X-1)^2+(Y+1)^2<=1; // то (X-1)^2+(Y+1)^2 меньше или равно 1
    }
    else {
      Y>=1; // иначе Y больше или равно 1
    }
    if ((X-1)^2+(Y+1)^2<=1) { // если (X-1)^2+(Y+1)^2 меньше или равно 1
        S==D; // то площадь равна фигуре D
    }
    else {
      S==0; // иначе площадь равна 0
    }
    if (Y>=1) { // если Y больше или равно 1
       (X-1)^2+(Y+1)^2>=1; // то (X-1)^2+(Y+1)^2 больше или равно 1
    }
    else {
      S==0; // иначе площадь равна 0
    }
    if ((X-1)^2+(Y+1)^2>=1) { // если (X-1)^2+(Y+1)^2 больше или равно 1
        X<=0; // то Х меньше или равно 0
    }
    else {
      S==0; // иначе площадь равна 0
    }
    if (X<=0) { // если Х меньше или равно 0
      S==A; // то площадь равна фигуре А
    }
    else {
      S==0; // иначе площадь равна 0
    }
    if (X>=0) { // если Х больше или равно 0
      X^2+Y^2<=1; // то X^2+Y^2 меньше или равно 1
    }
    else {
     X^2+Y^2>=1; // иначе X^2+Y^2 больше или равно 1
    }
    if (X^2+Y^2<=1) { // если X^2+Y^2 меньше или равно 1
      Y<=X-1; // то Y меньше или равно X-1
    }
    else {
     S==0; // иначе площадь равна 0
    }
    if (Y<=X-1) { // Y меньше или равно X-1
      S==C; // то площадь равна фигуре С
    }
    else {
     S==0; // иначе площадь равна 0
    }
    if (X^2+Y^2>=1) { // если X^2+Y^2 больше и равно 1
     Y>=X-1; // то Y больше или равно X-1
    }
    else {
     S==0; // иначе площадь равна 0
    }
    if (Y>=X-1) { // Y больше или равно X-1
     S==C; // то площадь равна фигуре С
    }
    else {
     S==0; // иначе площадь равна 0
    }

     cout <<"S\n"; // вывод

    return 0; // окончание выполнение функции
}
 '''
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас нигде нет ввода переменной. То, что вы называете вводом - просто объявление. В переменных при этом какой-то мусор, который вы начинаете с чем-то сравнивать...

Должно быть примерно так:

```
int X; 
cout << "Enter X: ";
cin >> X;   // ввод переменной
cout <<"X = " << X << "\n"; // вывод переменной на экран
```

Comment: я так сделала у переменной Y и X - у меня выводится только Х, как сделать, чтобы обе переменные выводились

Comment: Точно так же написать и для Y - заменив все X на Y.